# NativeScript Debugging with Android fails

Tags: android, npm, visual-studio-code, nativescript

I am new to mobile development and NativeScript. I am trying to find out how to debug my app rather than just putting console.log statements.

I am using Visual Studio Code as my text editor on Windows 10  machine with Visual Studio Emulator for Android or Genymotion Emulator.

I tried to debug using Chrome as explained [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/android/debug/debug-cli) and also tried using [NativeScript Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-vscode-extension)

With debugging using NativeScript CLI, project successfully opens Chrome browser but throws a 404 error.

```
tns debug android --debug-brk
```

[image: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404]

With Visual Studio Code extension, i receive this error:

[image: Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly]

and I see an error in the command prompt.
[image: Cannot find module 'source-map']

I tried suggestions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515336/how-debug-nativescript-code) SO post, though this problem is with Chromium, but that did not help.

Comment: Head over to the Nativescript CLI's Github page and open up an issue. The Nativescript community on SO is not that wide spead, so you've got a better chance of getting an answer over there.

Comment: Sure. Thanks @MikeResoli