# Debugging NativeScript-Vue when using vue-cli-template

Tags: debugging, vue.js, nativescript, vue-cli, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to figure out the right way to debug apps written in NativeScript-Vue AND using the "vue-cli-template".

There are currently two templates supported:

1. "nativescript-vue-template"

---

This one is much simpler, and debugging it is easy. There is a [useful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515336/how-debug-nativescript-code) on that already. The debugging is done using chrome-devtools. This template doesn't use vue-cli/Webpack/Babel, so the "Sources" that you can view in Chrome are not changed in any way. You can easily set breakpoints there.
Just run e.g.:

```
tns debug android
```

You can also use the very nice VS Code plugin.

2. "vue-cli-template"

---

This one uses vue-cli/Webpack/Babel, so that the .vue Single File Components can be compiled in different ways.

**Using a fresh install of the "vue-cli-template" as an example:**

Run:

```
npm run debug:android
```

When you view the "Sources" of the "Hello world" demo app provided in the template, the app.js file has 17700 lines of code. It is basically the compiled dist/app/app.android.js file.

I've got some experience with vue-cli based applications. In an application configured according to the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html), when you view the "Sources" in Chrome dev-tools, apart from the compiled sources you can access the "webpack://" node, which contains the original code. You can set breakpoints there and it works.

Unfortunately the "vue-cli-template" does not work this way. There is no "webpack://" node available. You can only access the compiled sources.

I tried to follow the mentioned [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html) to fix this. I'm supposed to add

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

to the vue.config.js file.
The template does not have it. Should I create one? If so, where?
Maybe I need other Webpack configurations?

Answer (score 0):

```
devtool: 'source-map'
```

recommended in [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/debugging-in-vscode.html) doesn't work in this setup.
It started working when I used:

```
devtool: 'eval-source-map'
```

after reading [Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/).

I added this option directly to the webpack.config.js file - without using any vue.config.js file.